# Fixing clear float breakage

Tags: css, css-float

I am having trouble working out a way to fix an issue that is being caused by an element whose `after` selector has a *clear float* rule that is breaking the intended layout.  Please refer to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oersqLvv/).  I decided to post on SO because I cannot find a **clean** way of solving this.

Looking at the fiddle above, the intended result is for the blue area to be as high as to fully contain its children nodes but *not* any higher.  As you can see, that is not what's happening and instead the blue area is matching the height of the yellow area.  The cause of that is, I believe, two fold:

1. The wrapper of the blue and red areas (`.outer`) is **not** floated and employs a margin trick to align itself correctly, whereas the yellow area (`.sidebar`) **is** floated left.
2. The blue element (`.toolbar`) has an `after` selector containing a `clear: float` rule that is somehow referring back to `.sidebar`'s float (Why though?).

How, then, do I fix this in a clean way such that the blue area has the intended height?

---

Incidentally, here is a "fix" I came up with which I am troubling accepting since it very much feels hacky: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oersqLvv/1).  The trick consists of floating the inner wrapper of the blue and red elements (`.inner`).

Comment: you just need to apply `float:left` to (`.toolbar`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify the block formating context , so floated elements will be minded .

overflow, display, float and position can do this, your code with overflow :

```css
.wrapper {
}
.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}
.outer, .toolbar {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.toolbar {
  background-color: blue;
}
.group {
  float: right;
}
.content {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="toolbar">
          <div class="group">
            <button>
              Test
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div>
            TEST
          </div>
          Lorem ipsum
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

see for more information: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/